# SwiftUI VStack and Spacer not behaving according to docs

Tags: swift, swiftui, layout, apple-watch

In a SwiftUI Apple Watch app, we need some text aligned in a vertical scroll view such that:

- if the content is small, it should be placed at the bottom of the screen.
- if the content does not fit into the lower half of the screen, it should extend off-screen at the bottom, such that the user has to scroll down to view the rest of the content.

Here's my take so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      ZStack {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
          VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
              .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height / 2)
            Text("Title")
              .bold()
              .background(.red.opacity(0.2))
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
              .background(.red.opacity(0.2))
          }
            .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height - 20)
            .background(.blue.opacity(0.4))
        }
      }
        .padding(10)
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    }
      .ignoresSafeArea()
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `Spacer` and the `frame(minHeight: ...)` part serve to place the content on the bottom. The `ScrollView`'s size is fixed to the whole screen.

However, the text is not displayed in full. Here's how it looks:

[image]

As you can see, the content does not start in the middle of the screen. Apparently the `Spacer` gets larger than its `minHeight`. However, the `Spacer` is documented to only take excess space in a `VStack`. There is not any excess space in that `VStack`, so the `Spacer` should only be as tall as its `minHeight`.

What am I missing?

And here's how it looks when scrolled to the bottom:

[image]

Why is this text clipped?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you're looking for (maybe a basic diagram would help). Should the title and main text stay together? Is it if the title and text fits, place at the bottom (meaning the bottom text is touching the bottom edge) - and then if the title and text doesn't fit, start from where? The top of the watch face, or the bottom out-of-sight? I've just got a hard time imagining exactly what you want

Comment: @George Title and main text should stay together, yes. If the title and text fits, place them at the bottom, yes. If they don't fit, start from the vertical middle of the screen. In other words: first, the bottom of the text touches the bottom edge of the screen. If title and text are larger than (vertical) half of the screen, extend them "below the screen", such that the top edge of the title "touches" the vertical center of the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important part to fix this is the layout priority. To prevent the `Spacer` from infinitely expanding (because `ScrollView` will give however much space its contents want) we need to define which takes priority. Without defining priority, by default SwiftUI appears to just evenly distribute the layout between the `Spacer` and all the `Text`s 50/50.

We can **reduce** the priority of the `Spacer` expanding with the [`layoutPriority(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/layoutpriority(_:)) modifier. A few other minor adjustments were made, such as setting a minimum height for the `VStack` so the text aligns to the bottom when it is short.

Full code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: geo.size.height / 2)
                        .layoutPriority(-1)

                    Text("Title")
                        .bold()
                        .background(.red.opacity(0.2))

                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
//                    Text("Much shorter text.")
                        .background(.red.opacity(0.2))
                }
                .frame(minHeight: geo.size.height)
                .background(.blue.opacity(0.4))
            }
        }
        .padding(10)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Result:

| Long text | Short text |
| --- | --- |
| [image: long text] | [image: short text] |

Answer (score 1):

You don't need spacer at all, instead alignment can be done by frame alignment, which is more appropriate in considered scenario

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2) // << fixed !!
                    Text("Title")
                        .bold()
                        .background(.red.opacity(0.2))
                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
                        .background(.red.opacity(0.2))
                }
                .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height - 20, alignment: .bottom) // << !!
                .background(.blue.opacity(0.4))
            }
        }
        .padding(10)
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.2

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the `Spacer` solution does not work?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, it does not really satisfy our demands. The text should be displayed in the lower half of the screen by default. Only when the user scrolls down, the text should also occupy the upper half. In your solution, the text is not displayed in the lower part.

Comment: If I understood your comment correctly then you just need to give exact height like `Spacer().frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2)`, otherwise it just grows as far as allowed by OS starting from minHeight, because in the provided layout there is not limit: a) VStack also has only minHeight, so can grow as far as pushed, b) ScrollView does not have own size at all. So you gave no limitation and transfer responsibility to OS, and OS balanced somehow... as you see.

Comment: Well, I can only repeat my requirements: Initially (before scrolling), the text must be contained to the lower half of the screen. If the text height is smaller than half of the screen height, it should be aligned to the bottom. If the text does not fit to the lower half of the screen, it should extend to the bottom, so that the user has to scroll to see all of it. This would be super-easy to do with a flex layout, but apparently it is quite complex in SwiftUI?